# How to delete rows with only NaN and 0 values in a DataFrame with Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

here is a DataFrame :

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'a': [12, 13, 45, '', 43, '', 78],
                     'b': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     'c': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     'd': ['dede', 'sese', 'sasa', '', 'cece', 'cfcf', 'fdfdfd'],
                     'e': [34, 67, 98, '', 99, '', 909]})
```

I would like to detect and delete rows with 0 and NaN values.
In the reality, the DataFrame has thousand rows  with 85 rows with only 0 and NaN values.

Maybe you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One Way:

```
df = df[~df.isin([0, np.NAN, '']).all(1)]
```

OR:

```
# df = df.replace('', np.NAN)
df = df.iloc[df.mask(df.eq(0)).dropna(how='all').index]
```